# Hide bootstrap element by class that is inside a specific div

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-multiselect

I would like to hide the `bootstrap multiselect select all button` by the following class: `.multiselect-item.multiselect-all` that is inside a specific div(That class is added by bootstrap onto HTML `Select`). Currently I hide it with `javascript` like this:

```
$('.multiselect-item.multiselect-all').addClass('hidden');
```

But what that does is it hides that element everywhere on the page. I only want hide it in a specified div. I've tried using .parent(), .find(), none which have worked. Any help is much appreciated. I use bootstrap multiselect.

**My HTML**

```
<select id="typeCheckboxSelect" class="selectpicker" name="typeSelector[]" multiple="multiple">
   <option class='typeCheckbox' type='checkbox' value='test1'>Test One</option>
   <option class='typeCheckbox' type='checkbox' value='test2'>Test Two</option>
   <option class='typeCheckbox' type='checkbox' value='test3'>Test Three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple select plugin actually hides your original `select` element besides its own custom element. So, to hide the desired item, you need to modify your selector a bit more:

```
$('#typeCheckboxSelect ~ div ul li.multiselect-item.multiselect-all').addClass('hidden');
```

The above selector will only target the **Select All** button of the multiple select box which is created as a shadow of `#typeCheckboxSelect`.

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what i needed! May I ask what is the ~ used for?

Comment: @CrimzonWeb -- A simple google search would have shown you. Anyway [here you go](https://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/).

Answer (score 0):

Does Bootstrap add the `.multiselect-item.multiselect-all` to the select element? If so, you can just add the div's class to your jquery selector to target all divs with that specific class name.

`$('.selectpicker.multiselect-item.multiselect-all')`

Comment: Interestingly enough, I tried that exact solution and it did not help me. Thank you tho! Fortunately got a working solution from 31piy answer.